# How can I create a common post build event used by multiple csproj projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have several Visual Studio 2010 C# projects. I'd like to have them all have the same post build event. Basically I want them to copy their output somewhere. I think I can do this using an <import> statement in each csproj file, but I can't seem to figure out the properties/targets and such that I need in the imported file. Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT: I've tried the following but can't get it to work. This is what the Imports.props file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Message Text="Here I come to save the day!" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I then Include it in the csproj files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="Imports.props" />
    ...
```

I've also tried this as Imports.props:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PostBuildEvent>echo Here I come to save the day!</PostBuildEvent>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you import your targets file *after* the Microsoft.Common.targets import, as that file defines an empty AfterBuild target, which would override the definition in your targets file.

Comment: Bingo. I had the import at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`<import>` in each projectfile and a `<AfterBuild>` target in your common build file.

CommonTargets
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171464.aspx

TargetOrder
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work as advertised. I'll edit my question and add some source.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to share a build script via the property sheets, by writing it as a macro in the inherited property sheet. Then calling the macro in any of the projects that need them.

Macros are found under (VS2005):
Common Properties->User Macros

Remember, you can put macros inside other macros so long as the order is correct.